# Laravel: Incorrectly displayed date of messages from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Now I send a message to my inbox app. You can see saved a message in image:
[image]

Message send in **16:55**. But in my local site date of message incorrectly displayed:
[image]
Why is the date sent message not displayed correctly? Laravel app config timezone set `"Asia/Tashkent"`

#### Code:

```
$today = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->latest()->paginate($perPage);

$thisYear = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfYear(), Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay()])->latest()->paginate($perPage);

$pastYear = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)->where('created_at', '<', now()->startOfYear())->latest()->paginate($perPage);
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I'm under the impression that you may have used `h:m`, and it displays 01 because the date's month is 1. Try `h:i` instead if that's the case.

Comment: You included the code, but where is the part where you format this date to print in the page?

Comment: `created_at->format('H:m')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, you're formatting this date with `created_at->format('H:m')`.

In PHP,  `m` refers to the month, not the minute, which is `i`. It's printing `01` because that's the date's month.

Use this instead:

```
created_at->format('H:i')
```

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly wrote the wrong meaning. Thanks @Phiter

Answer (score 1):

Please try that way :

```
$today = Inbox::where($message, $user_id)->whereDate('created_at',DB::raw('CURDATE()'))->latest()->paginate($perPage);
```

Let’s say you want to filter out entries created today. You have a timestamp field created_at, right? How do you filter the DATE only from that timestamp? Apparently, Taylor thought about it.

I’ve seen people doing it with raw queries, like this:

```
$q->where(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) = '".date('Y-m-d')."'"));
```

Or without raw queries by datetime, like this:

```
$q->where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'));
```

Luckily, Laravel Query Builder offers a more Eloquent solution:

```
$q->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

Or, of course, instead of PHP date() you can use Carbon:

```
$q->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

Comment: Why you want replace `Carbon::today()` to `DB::raw('CURDATE()')` @Nims Patel?